# Update Excel Userform From Worksheet Cells

Tags: excel, vba, automation, userform

I have the following userform in one macro-enabled excel workbook. It needs me to fill all the empty cells every time and click update to set the cell values to be used for further calculations. I am looking forward to finding an alternative to fill these cells from the worksheet range and by-pass clicking this **Update** button.

I am new to VBA and struggling to answer this for a month now, any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[image: User Form Sample]

Comment: `TextBoxA1 = Range("A1")`

Comment: You may want to see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). `I'm very new to VBA so I don't have a code to show.` Being new to VBA is no excuse :) You can spend some time learning the language. And once you have tried some code you can then post the code sharing **1.** What were you expecting? **2.** What is not working? Include Error message if applicable

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments here. This one, for now, is a pre-existing setup where I am just trying to simplify the process, and to start with this has a big script in the backend that I cannot share. Would read what you suggested perhaps be useful in future.

Answer (score 0):

This looks very simple issue. Try below codes. Adjust `sheet` name and textbox names to `UserForm` as well as cells addresses.

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
    Me.TextBox1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Me.txtMyBox = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I need to update this without clicking the button, so here cmdupdate_click is something I need to bypass. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Then write codes to `UserForm_Initialize` event.